# Does Python's ThreadPoolExecutor terminate idle threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

Will Python's ThreadPoolExecutor terminate idle threads to cut down on resource usage when the pool isn't being heavily used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but in `Python 3.8+` it will [avoid](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L193-L196) creating new threads if there are idle threads already.

In the example below, I've set the `max_workers` argument to 50 but only 2 threads were created (to run 5 tasks) and the number of threads stay the same:

```
>>> from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
>>> def test(n):
...     return n * n
... 
>>> executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50)
>>> len(executor._threads)
0
>>> features = [executor.submit(test, i) for i in range(5)]
>>> len(executor._threads)
2
>>> [f.result() for f in features]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> len(executor._threads)
2
>>> features = [executor.submit(test, i) for i in range(10000)]
>>> len(executor._threads)
50
```